# Remove index from all Vespa cluster nodes

Tags: vespa

Is there a way to remove an index (its documents) from all the nodes of the same cluster ?

For now, I'm following [this](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/vespa-cmdline-tools.html#vespa-remove-index) command:

```
$ /opt/vespa/bin/vespa-stop-services && /opt/vespa/bin/vespa-remove-index -force && /opt/vespa/bin/vespa-start-services
```

But it only removes the documents from the current node, and I am forced to run it on each node of the cluster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the quickest way to remove all docs, yes. Make sure to stop all nodes so nodes do not sync while doing it. There is no global purge all docs feature - it would be handy, though.

The alternative is to use visit to get all ids, then create a feed to purge the docs. It normally takes longer, but kind of easier, depending on number of nodes. Kristian, Vespa Team

Comment: @dkurzaj: Feel free to file GitHub issue requesting "global purge doc" feature:

https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/new